# using multiple exclusions for @Before in play framework 1.2.3 (or 1.2.4)

Tags: playframework

I've tried multiple exclusions with @Before in Play framework 1.2.3 (see below) but it does not appear whether I can do so or perhaps I am using an incorrect syntax.  I do not wish to use 'only' with multiple values unless there is no other way around it.  The first one works, the second does not.

This works:

```
@Before(unless="login")
```

This one does not work:

```
@Before(unless="login", "signup")
```

Comment: found the answer: pilot error - need to pass in the values into an array i.e. {"login","signup"}

Comment: as you have answered the question, copy your comment into the answer box, and mark it as correct for future people to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to pass in the values into an array i.e. {"login","signup"} - which works on play 1.2.3.